# Solubility specification in a standard

Tags: solubility, analytical-chemistry

I'm reading a standard where under the specification for a substance it says:

> Solubility in Alcohol: 1 ml in 3 ml 50% alcohol remains clear to 8
>   ml.

Just wanted to confirm my interpretation: I make a 50-50 Ethanol + Water solution (w/w) and then add 1 ml of test-sample to 3 ml of this solution. This should remain clear.

Then I continue adding more of the alcohol solution till total quantity is 8 ml & throughout the mixture must stay clear?

Is this right? Any comments?

Edit:

Here is a supplier specification from Sigma Aldrich which has a variation of the same wording:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing but that doesn't sound right.  Are you preparing a standard (of what) from a concentrate of the substance?  What is the substance?  If you can be specific I'm pretty sure we can come up with the answers you need.

Comment: @airhuff Thanks. No, not preparing a standard. Just reading a published standard for specifications of a chemical and this is one of the tests mentioned. I am just trying to interpret the test procedure correctly. From the wording it wasn't clear to me what the procedure should be.  I will post an image of the actual standard if I can.

Comment: That would be very helpful!

Comment: @airhuff I can't find my copy of the original standard but Sigma Aldrich is a regular supplier of the chemical and their version of the specifications also lists the same (but slight modification in quantities) test. Does this help? All I need to know is what the wording of the test means. i.e. What is to be done and how are the results to be interpreted. I have given my interpretation of the test procedure. Does that look right to you?

Comment: What you have said seems correct.  I don't know why you are doing that though, but so long as you do all is good I guess.  Is this a turbidity standard, or indicator?  Sigma's "Solubility (Turbidity)" looks a bit unfamiliar to me.  Also, they say the solubility is 1 ml in 2 ml, so where you say w/w I think should be v/v.  I'm still very curious what the chemical is.  I'm not sure I've helped you much here.

Comment: @airhuff Thank you! The why is simple: I have a sample of this material from a Manufacturer that wants to make sure its product meets the spec.

Comment: Ohhh, interesting, thanks for clarifying!  Glad to be of some help anyway and good luck.